# jQuery filter results for classes with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I just started using jQuery, then forgive me for noobish.
What I'm trying to do is 'get reference to a object that is wrapped in a class', but there are more classes with same name.
How can I reach the right object and get the reference to it, when the only thing that will differ it from a thousand other more objects is the text inside the div.

In this case, I'm trying to show only the text "this should be returned", that is under the classes 'ng-anyclass'.
After that, will be possible store the reference to that specific div and change it text? Or any other properties?

Here's the code:
Page 1 - the loader:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function($){
                var s = $('#result').load('Page2.html .ng-anyclass .ng-anyclass .ng-anyclass');

                });
            </script>
     </head>
        <body>
            <div id="result"></div>
            <div>Other Stuff Here</div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Page 2 - the target page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="ng-anyclass">
                <div class="ng-anyclass">
                    <div class="ng-anyclass">this should be returned</div>
                </div>
                <div class="ng-anyclass">
                    <div class="ng-anyclass">not this</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:eq(0)` for this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#result').load('page2.html .ng-anyclass .ng-anyclass .ng-anyclass:eq(0)', function(){
    var _this = $(this)
          setTimeout(function(){
            _this.find('.ng-anyclass').text('changed');
          },1000);
      });
});
```

#### [updated plnkr Demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQX2sK6aNRuER5rLgcta?p=preview)

Comment: Reading your answer, now question makes more sense to me... :) But what is the purpose of timeout here?

Comment: Oh! thanks @A.Wolff it was to let him see that it changes after load.

Comment: I guess OP would want something like that: `'page2.html .ng-anyclass .ng-anyclass .ng-anyclass:contains("specific string")'`

Comment: @A.Wolff but the snippet above already did, but I'll try yours too. Thank you!

Comment: @FabricioSomini It depends if you want to filter it by text or by index. If what you want is always in first matched position, then avoid using `:contains()`

Comment: @A.Wolff I'll be using both options, case I have a lot of cases. Fixed index,  and by text! Thank you all

Comment: I can't upvote answers yet, as soon as I can, I'll. Ty

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write text somewhere you can use CSS selector, like this :

```
$('body .ng-anyclass .ng-anyclass:eq(0) .ng-anyclass').text('your text')
```

eq(0) it's a shortcut of first-child, or eq(1) is nth-child(2) for example

I hope it will be help you

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!